# what is the correct way to change the directions of Winforms controls

Tags: c#, winforms

what is the correct way to change the directions/position of `Winforms` controls, so it supports for example languages that start from `Right-To-Left`, programmatically so it's one form , one design, but when I switch the languages , it's switches it's position and directions.

EDIT: after checking @vcsjones answer ;

it worked with the layout ,but the controls position didn't change. here an image 
[image]

I have tried nested loops to change the direction , but it didn't work :

```
    if (Constantes["RightToLeft"] != null && Constantes["RightToLeft"].ToLower().Equals("true"))
    {
        RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
        RightToLeftLayout = true;


        foreach (Control c in base.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control item in c.Controls)
            {
                foreach (Control i in item.Controls)
                {
                    i.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
                }
                item.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
            }
            c.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

WinForms can already handle this reasonably well using the right-to-left unicode character. For example:

```
button1.Text = "\u202EHello World";
```

This will display the button's text way like this:

[image: RTL Hello World]

Most likely, your text of your application will be done using localization files. If you use the RTL unicode character in the strings of your localization file, then you do not need to do any special coding - that unicode character is handled by WinForms already.

Setting these two properties will also switch around the control layout of the window:

```
RightToLeftLayout = true;
RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

[image]

Comment: it worked with the form layout , but not with the controls , here 
http://i.imgur.com/FbWWlOx.png , the `labales and textboxes` should be flipped, but it didn't, I can't add the codes here so I will edit the question.

here is the code

Comment: @MixedCoder You need to add your controls to a `Panel` that supports the `RightToLeft` property (e.g. `FlowLayoutPanel`). If you add your controls to the `Form` using X-Y coordinates, then they won't be flipped.